# Using Trigger to Create new records using after insert and select from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select, triggers, insert

Hoping someone can help me. I've tried numerous variations of triggers I've found but can't seem to get the result I'm after. I've only been able to get this to work for a single record but fails on multiple. I know it's wrong but I'll post the code just so it doesn't look like I'm trying to get someone to build the trigger for me.

Here is the scenario. I have a product, location and stock table. What I want to do is automatically add the product number to the stock table with a balance of 0 after a new product is entered. But it needs to have a record for each location so Lets say location East and West for now but could be more added. That way when the location has stock arrive they can update their stock as is goes in and out.

Here is what I have now.

```
USE [TestInventory]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BalanceUpdate] ON [dbo].[Parts]
FOR INSERT
AS 
declare @PartNumber varchar(50);
declare @Balance smallint = '0';
declare @Location smallint;

SELECT @Location = (Select ID from Location);
Select @PartNumber = PartNumber from inserted ;

Insert into Stock_Balance 
(PartNumber, Location, Balance) Values(@PartNumber, @Location, @Balance);
```

Of course that fails because of the multiple location ID records. I normally just struggle through these until I stumble across the coding that works but really need help on this one. Thanks to all the contribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert multiple rows of `Location`. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Stock_Balance(PartNumber, Location, Balance))
SELECT @PartNumber, ID, @Balance
FROM Location
```

Your trigger would now be:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BalanceUpdate] ON [dbo].[Parts]
FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @PartNumber VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Balance SMALLINT = '0';
SELECT @PartNumber = PartNumber FROM inserted ;

INSERT INTO Stock_Balance(PartNumber, Location, Balance)
    SELECT @PartNumber, ID, @Balance
    FROM Location
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you so much. So frustrating when you dance around the solution and then finally see it.